# ProgrammaticLogin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I use ProgrammaticLogin in Glassfish 3.1.2 with username,password and realm and it works good. Anyway when I call context.getCallerPrincipal() I get org.glassfish.security.common.PrincipalImpl with context.getCallerPrincipal().getName() which returns the username.

Is there any way that I can pass Principle via ProgrammaticLogin
so it is passed in my ejb and available from SessionContext - context.getCallerPrincipal()?

Comment: Anyone had the same problem ???

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in a context where resource-injection is not possible via annotations. 
You can try to get an instance of the desired EJB via a manual JNDI lookup.

Example:

```
InitialContext init = new InitialContext();
YourBean bean = (YourBean) init.lookup(JNDI_NAME_OF_YOUR_BEAN);
```

Now you should be able to pass the Principal to your bean.